# Echoing in php without changing pages

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a simple input form on my site for people to enter in information for submission.  The code looks like this in the case they do not enter anything:

this is form.php

```
if ($_POST['q'])  == NULL ){
   echo "Please enter your information"
```

The code works great, but it sends the user to form.php with the echo, where I want this to be echoed on my main page index.html right below the input box - basically so it doesn't navigate away from the page.  Is this doable in php or will I need some javascript.  I would have searched for ways to do this but I don't know what this method is called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

dont set a action in the url and it will submit to its self, if that still wont work you will need rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it postback to itsself and then redirect the page to post.php?q=value if there is a value else echo below the input field.

```
<?php
$qisempty = false;
if(!empty($_POST['q']))
{
    header("Location:http://../post.php?q=".$_POST['q']);
}
else
    $qisempty = true;
?>
    <input name="q" type="text">
    <?php if($qisempty) echo "Please enter your information";?>
```

Comment: Do I need to create a text field in my html file to post this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to navigate away from the page you will need to use Javascript. Add a onSubmit to the form, and then let the function you call there return false, if the input is not complete and the form should not be submitted.

Comment: Is there a good point of reference for how to accomplish this online?

Comment: @user695653 http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/validation.shtml and then you can enter some text into a div, p or whatever with a given id like this: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php (Instead of the alert)

Comment: you dont need javascript Mostly because what if javascript is disabled

Comment: @Laurence Burke: I think the best option is AJAX for what he is asking, but combined with php redirection back to the same page as in the other answers.  That way if users have javascript, the form is responsive, else it still works the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX for this thing. AJAX is great for this type of problems when you don't want to reload pages to do task in specific place or Div of HTMLpages.

For your problem, You need to create a HTML file with your form in it, and submit it via AJAX. and get your response via same AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_ajax(val1,val2,param1,param2,subfile){
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = subfile;
var params = val1+"="+param1+"&"+val2+"="+param2;
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
        //Remove the alert and use whatever you want to do with http.responsetext like
    // document.getElementById("YourDiv").innerHTML=document.getElementById("YourDiv").innerHTML +http.responsetext
    }
}
http.send(params);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
<input type="text" id="user" value="user" name="user" />
<input type="password" id="password" value="pass" name="pass" />
<button onclick="submit_ajax(user.name,password.name,user.value,password.value, "submit_file.php");">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="YourDiv">
<!--Something appears here after callback-->
</div>
```

This was the first page. Now Use your script in your PHP file(probably, submit_file.php) as you want and then echo the text you want in your div by validation or something.. a sample would be

```
<?php

$username=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

if(validateuser($username,$password)){
    if(checkuserpass($username,$password){
        echo "You were successfully logged in!";
    }
echo "Sorry Username/Password Mismatch";
}
else {
echo "There was an error in your input!Please Correct";
}
?>
```

Hope you got what you wanted...

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be assigning the error message to a variable called (e.g $errorMsg) 
the printing it on page using a echo or print function.

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['q'])  == NULL ){
       $errorMsg =' Please enter your information';
    }

    ?>
```

Place this code where you want the error to appear

```
<? print $errorMsg; ?>
```